# Insert time Information with Data

Tags: node-red

I am using Cloudant node on the Node-red to store data that comes from SensorTag. Is it possible to get time information for this data?
I tried to include the time information from the gateway device that is publishing the sensor tag data. Also, I tried to  get the current time via a function node once I receive the data in the Node-RED flow. However, I always get some error!
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Update the question with details of the error so we have a chance to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example get current time and store it to an incoming message's property. Add a `change node`, after a data input node, similar to this:

```
[{"id":"7be0c7a8.d5674","type":"change","z":"47849408.20a044","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"time","pt":"msg","to":"","tot":"date"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":444,"y":577,"wires":[[]]}]
```

Then you can access the timestamp on `msg.time`